# Google Spreadsheet Lookup question?

Tags: google-sheets

Needing some help with google sheets. SO I have a sheet named 2016 with invoices listed and information on them within that row.  I need a new sheet named "unpaid" to pull all of the unpaid invoices.

Lets say the column reads (column title for A, B, C...):
Invoice date, Invoice #, Paid/unpaid, Invoice Amount, Brokerage rate

I need "Unpaid" sheet to pull information IF invoice is unpaid and then pull the relevant information.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like what you are looking for is not a lookup formula. You can use the FILTER formula to accomplish what you are asking.

Assuming your sheet "2016" and sheet "unpaid" have completely identical column headers ( In Ranges A1:E1 ). I put the following formula in the "unpaid" sheet in range A2: `=FILTER('2016'!A:E,'2016'!C:C="unpaid")`

The first part of the Filter formula asks which range are you importing? The second asks what criteria are you using to reduce the number of results.

Google Sheets also allows you to use the curly-brackets not only to explicitly define arrays, but also to combine separate ranges into one array. SO, if you don't want the "Paid/unpaid" column in your "unpaid" sheet. You can instead use the formula: `=FILTER({'2016'!A:B,'2016'!D:E},'2016'!C:C="unpaid")`